# How to create a byte variable that change value during for loop in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, byte, utf-16

I want to print differences between utf-8 and utf-16 for all characters in range `\x00\x00\x00\x00` to `\xff\xff\xff\xff` and I was thinking to do in this way:

```
for i in range (0x10):
  h = hex(i)[2:3]
  byte = b"\x00\x00\x00\x0{i}"

print(byte.decode('utf-16', 'ignore'))
print(byte.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

where the i into the byte variable change during the loop and using nested loop to cover all bytes in byte variable.
Is possible to do something like that?
Exists another way to print all byte from `\x00\x00\x00\x00` to `\xff\xff\xff\xff` in python?

Comment: Realize there are 4 billion+ combinations.  That's a lot of printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `struct` module is a nice tool to build byte strings. Here you could generate yours that way:

```
for i in range(0x10):
    b = struct.pack('>I', i)   # convert an int to a big endian 4 bytes string
    print(b)
```

It gives as expected:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x02'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x03'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x04'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x05'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x06'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x07'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x08'
b'\x00\x00\x00\t'
b'\x00\x00\x00\n'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x0b'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x0c'
b'\x00\x00\x00\r'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x0e'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x0f'
```